# Add ng-mocks as an independent tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-disambiguation

Currently, it's impossible to use [ng-mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-mocks) as a tag. When you attempt to create it, you are informed it's too similar to [ngmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngmock) in the following error:

> The tag [ng-mocks] is too similar to [ngmock]. If you think this tag should be allowed, discuss it on meta.

[ng-mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-mocks) is a library to mock declarations in Angular 5+:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-mocks

[ngmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngmock) is a part of AngularJS (Angular 1), and isn't present in Angular 2+: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock

The proposal is:

- to rename [ngmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ngmock) to [angularjs-ngmock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angularjs-ngmock), because AngularJS has been deprecated and isn't supported: https://blog.angular.io/discontinued-long-term-support-for-angularjs-cc066b82e65a
- to add [ng-mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-mocks) as it is, because [ng-mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ng-mocks) is for Angular 5+, including latest Angular 13

Comment: I'm honestly sceptical this would happen. I though you were implying that [[tag:ng-mocks]] is a synonym of [[tag:ngmock]] but it isn't. I don't really want to create a sandbox question on [main], so is therr a specific question that you've seen that should be tagged with it? Ideally though, considering how similar the existing tag and your suggestion is, I would personally suggest they be more disambiguated.

Comment: no, I don't imply that `ng-mocks` is a synonym of `ngMock`, they are two different libraries. However, if you try to add `ng-mocks` as a tag on `stackoverflow`, it replaces it with `ngmock` and suggests to raise a discussion here in order to add a new tag for `ng-mocks`.

Comment: You didn't state you were getting an error when you tried, @satanTime... you should have. The fact you are and what that error says solidifies my suggestion: *"Ideally though, considering how similar the existing tag and your suggestion is, I would personally suggest **they be more disambiguated.**"*

Comment: Again, like I said, I would suggest you disambiguate. Would, for example, [[tag:npmjs-ng-mocks]] be suitable? I know nothing of the technologies, so to me I could easily get those 2 tags confused, and so I suspect others than are new (to the technology) could too, so if you can suggest a rename for [[tag:ngmock]] and an appropriate unambiguous tag for Ng-mocks you'd be making a much better suggestion, in my opinion.

Comment: npmjs is a package manager, like many others. The right way is to rename `ngmock` to `angularjs-ngMock` and to add `ng-mocks` as it is, because `ng-mocks` is for Angular 5+ (Including latest Angular 13), and AngularJS has been deprecated and isn't supported: https://blog.angular.io/discontinued-long-term-support-for-angularjs-cc066b82e65a

Comment: @Larnu we don't use the repository of the library for tags anywhere. That only makes sense when you are a repository recompiling someones assets (like debian's r-cran-* and perl-cpan-*), not for tags.

Comment: @Braiam this is why I explicitly said *"I **know nothing** of the technologies"*. I didn't pretend I did; they were suggestions of disambiguation bnased on zero knowledge other than, from someone with *zero* knowledge, they look *very* similar and so ideally shouldn't...

Comment: @Larnu even if you didn't know, you should know that npmjs is merely a package repository, and from there infer that that's unlikely to be on the tag name.

Comment: No, no I don't know it's a package manager, @Braiam (well I do *now*). [I know *nothing*. I am from Barcelona](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nX7CeTXoxyU).

Comment: Seeing as AngularJS is now EOL it makes sense that [ng-mocks] should take precedence over [ngmock]. And seeing as there is only 1 question tagged [ngmock], with 0 answers, and it was 5 years ago, I don't see how there could possibly be any confusion over [ng-mocks] if we did go ahead renaming [ngmock] and adding [ng-mocks]

Comment: I've created the [tag:ng-mocks] tag via [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71325882/providemockstore-with-mockbuilder-in-ng-mocks). There seem to be a few other questions using [tag:ngmock] which will now need to be disambiguated. I haven't got the time right at the moment to do this myself, so I've removed the blocker for others to do so in the mean time. Once it's cleaned up I'll rename the original tag